# Latin America (Brazil?) short stories. Just recall fragments: A lone traveler

Tags: identification-request, short-stories, spanish-language

The protagonist, a traveler to some distant town narrating the stories. In some of them, he sees another figure on the horizon, shadowing him. In one of the stories (an early one in the collection) there is a scene of cattle trying to cross a swollen river in a storm. That's about all I can recall, except they were brilliantly written stories. The name "Segudo" pops into my head, but I've looked under that name and found nothing. Wish I had more clues to offer. In the end, I think he arrives at his destination.

Comment: The tag [[tag:spanish-literature]] has a specific meaning here: literature which was originally in the Spanish language. Do you think that would be the case, from what you remember?

Comment: Don't know for certain, but certain it was a Latin-American writer, and the stories had a South American flavor to them, mostly rural settings. So I would say yes, the tag applies.

There was one other short story that I think was also in the collection (but can't be certain). It opens with the sound of a female mosquito buzzing in a darkened room. The next scene is two old men, good friends, on a porch, just chatting. The village is empty, no one left but them.  One confesses, when they were very young he was in love with the other's wife. The conversation goes downhill from there.